# Ajax call Laravel Route

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, upload, routes

How do I properly call a Laravel Route or Controller in my Ajax?

An error appears and says:

> Route [product/create] not defined. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\jsBlade\logoInput.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\jsBlade\logoInput.blade.php)

My Routes look like this:

```
# Middleware group if user is successfully logged in
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PageController@showHome']);

    # Product group
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'product'], function ()
    {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'indexProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@indexProduct']);
        Route::get('new', ['as' => 'newProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@newProduct']);
        Route::get('show/{productID}', ['as' => 'showProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@showProduct']);
        Route::get('edit/{productID}', ['as' => 'editProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@editProduct']);
        Route::post('create', ['as' => 'createProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@createProduct']);
        Route::post('update', ['as' => 'updateProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@updateProduct']);
        Route::delete('destroy', ['as' => 'destroyProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@destroyProduct']);
    });

});
```

My Ajax:

```
$("#input-logo").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: '{{route("product/create")}}',
    type: 'POST',
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"],
    allowedFileTypes: ['image'],
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-Token': $('#_token').val(),
    }
}).on('filepreupload', function() {
    $('#kv-success-box').html('');
}).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
    $('#kv-success-box').append(data.response.link);
    $('#kv-success-modal').modal('show');
});

</script>
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use App\Product;
use App\Companies;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function createProduct()
    {
        $data = Input::all();

        $product = new Product;

        $product->fill($data);
        if($product->save())
        {
            return redirect()->route('root')->with('message','Success');;
        }
    }
}
```

Firefox gives this error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data.

Answer (score 7):

Change this part

```
uploadUrl: '{{route("product/create")}}',
```

to this

```
uploadUrl: '{{url("product/create")}}',
```

and add a csrf token to your header in ajax

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
},
```

Comment: Hm ok now I get an other error message which says following:SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.

Comment: Firefox gave me a diffreent erro than google saying:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Answer (score 3):

Just Ajax to the URL of the route like this:

This is my route:

```
Route::post('users/send-file-temp',['uses'=>'UsersController@postSendFileTemp']);
```

and here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/send-file-temp',
});
```

Ajax will send the request to `/users/send-file-temp` and Laravel will recognize the route and direct it to the corresponding controller.

Answer (score 2):

Take not of your ajax **method type** and your **Route method** type

Example below

My Ajax code

```
    $('#sendMsg').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{url("R_E/users/sendMSG")}}',
        data: $("#form-signin").serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert("okay");

        }, 
        error: function(){
              alert("failure From php side!!! ");
         }

        }); 

        });
```

My route Code

Route::post('/users/sendMSG', 'RE\MainController@sendMSG');

Answer (score 0):

instead of `{{route("product/create")}}` ,
following one worked for me in Laravel 8 :

```
!{route("product/create")}!
```

Answer (score 0):

afaik you need to call the name of the assigned route. in your case, your routes still haven't had any names assigned to them. you can assign it with the command name() at the end of your code

```
Route::post('create', ['as' => 'createProduct', 'uses' => 
'ProductController@createProduct'])->name('product.create');
```

after you assign name into the route, you can then call it from route command.

```
$("#input-logo").fileinput({
uploadUrl: '{{route("product.create")}}',
type: 'POST',
allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"],
allowedFileTypes: ['image'],
headers: {
   'X-CSRF-Token': $('#_token').val(),
}}).on('filepreupload', function() {
$('#kv-success-box').html('');
}).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
$('#kv-success-box').append(data.response.link);
$('#kv-success-modal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

you can check your url and your route with the command
php artisan route:list
on your git bash or terminal and
[here's what you get][1]
on the left side, that's your **url**(with slashes)
on the right side, that's your **route name**(without slashes and before the '>' sign)

ah and yes. you don't need to always use route. you can use url. it's much easier anyway.

you guys can correct me if I'm wrong.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w6Mz.png